# Tensorflow Batch Normalization results dependent on number of channels in input

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, batch-normalization

I'm trying to port weights for batch normalization from tensorflow to pytorch and I encountered a strange issue in tensorflow. The below code excerpt computes batchnorm with 10 channels with input of purely ones and default batch norm parameters. You can see that last 2 channels compute to a different value than the rest for 10 channels in an input. We also get different results for different number of channels, I presented example of 5 and 8 channels inputs.

```
import os 
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
import tensorflow as tf

n_channels = 10

tef_inp = tf.keras.layers.Input((1,1,n_channels))
tef_out = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(tef_inp)
tef = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[tef_inp],outputs=[tef_out])
a = tf.ones([1, 1, 1, n_channels],dtype=tf.float32) 

tfo = tef(a,training=False)
tfo
```

And I get a results:
for n_channels=10:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1, 1, 10), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[0.9995002, 0.9995002, 0.9995002, 0.9995002, 0.9995002,
          0.9995002, 0.9995002, 0.9995002, 0.9995004, 0.9995004]]]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

for n_channels=5:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1, 1, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[0.9995004, 0.9995004, 0.9995004, 0.9995004, 0.9995004]]]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

for n_channels=8:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1, 1, 8), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[0.9995002, 0.9995002, 0.9995002, 0.9995002, 0.9995002,
          0.9995002, 0.9995002, 0.9995002]]]], dtype=float32)>
```

The problem is `0.9995004` and `0.9995002` results, even during the same inference. I know it is not big difference, but if we get multiple batch norms in a model it might very easily propagate into much bigger error.

I also tried computing it manually with tensorflow and numpy according to tensorflow documentation `gamma * (batch - self.moving_mean) / sqrt(self.moving_var + epsilon) + beta`, and I get the `0.9995004` result, so it seems `0.9995002` is simply wrong. I also tried this on two different machines and got the same results.
Here is the code for manual check:

```
import numpy as np
gamma = np.array([1.0]*10)
batch = np.array([1.0]*10)
mean_batch = np.array([0.0]*10)
epsilon = np.array(0.001)
beta = np.array([0.0]*10)
out = gamma * (batch - mean_batch) / np.sqrt(1.0 + epsilon) + beta
out

array([0.99950037, 0.99950037, 0.99950037, 0.99950037, 0.99950037,
       0.99950037, 0.99950037, 0.99950037, 0.99950037, 0.99950037])
```

```
n_channels = 10
gamma = tf.convert_to_tensor([1.0]*n_channels)
batch = tf.convert_to_tensor([1.0]*n_channels)
mean_batch = tf.convert_to_tensor([0.0]*n_channels)
epsilon = tf.convert_to_tensor(0.001)
beta = tf.convert_to_tensor([0.0]*n_channels)
out = gamma * (batch - mean_batch) / np.sqrt(1.0 + epsilon) + beta
out

<tf.Tensor: shape=(10,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0.9995004, 0.9995004, 0.9995004, 0.9995004, 0.9995004, 0.9995004,
       0.9995004, 0.9995004, 0.9995004, 0.9995004], dtype=float32)>
```

Tensorflow versions checked: 2.4.0 and 2.9.1
Numpy version checked: 1.21.5

So here are the questions:

1. Maybe I am doing something wrong, so can anyone point me in further debugging direction?
2. Maybe there is a good explanation for this behavior, then what is exactly the root cause of this results?
3. Finally, is there a way to reproduce these results in pytorch?

Comment: are you sure that 1e-7 is such a big deal?...

Comment: 1e-7 difference might not be influential, but we are talking about the difference using same input, same parameters and same implementation. That may propagate later into bigger errors if we just change number of channels.

Comment: You can see that the default value for `epsilon` is 1e-5, and that also will be a just an approximation, so I don't believe that 1e-7 might cause any possible problem, also considering that the rounding will be consistent "forever", and is not random noise that can propagate

Comment: Bias might be less problematic than random noise if he trains and evaluates in Tensorflow, because the model will compensate for it during training. However, it absolutely becomes an issue when you try porting weights to PyTorch which is the context he outlined in his question. 1e-7 for tens of channels quickly becomes 1e-6, which then becomes 1e-5 in architectures with many instances of BatchNorm. And that's assuming linear error propagation, which is obviously not the case for deep architectures.